# Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event using C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am getting below error.

> Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField does not have a DataBinding event.

I am doing visible condition in grid view BoundField. Below is my code

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="AssessmentStartdate" 
    HeaderText="Assessment Date" 
    DataFormatString="{0:d}" 
    SortExpression="AssessmentStartdate" 
    HeaderStyle-BackColor="#f1f1f1" 
    Visible='<%# Eval("DayType").ToString()=="Single" %>' >
</asp:BoundField>
```

Same visible condition is working using TemplateField. Why visible condition is not working with boundfield. Please waiting for your answer with code.

Comment: As the error says, you can't do that, you should use a TemplateField

Comment: Is any logic to do with BoundField. @hardkoded

Comment: The question there would be, do you want to hide the entire column or a cell?

Comment: Column. @hardkoded

Answer (score 3):

You can hide the column at runtime before performing the `DataBind`. In the following code, I'm assuming that `dayType` is part of the `DataTable`, and it's the same across the table, As you said that you want to hide the entire column I assume that the value is the same.

```
var data = GetData();
string dayType = string.Empty;
int boundFieldIndex = 4;

if(data.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    dayType = data.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>("dayType");
}

gridView.Columns[boundFieldIndex].Visible = dayType == "Single";
gridView.DataSource = data.Tables[0];
gridView.DataBind();
```